# Can I compare if the outputs of different Generalized least-squares models are distinct in a statistically significant manner?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, generalized-least-squares, phylogeny

So I want to compare whether using human scoring or using modelling of avian vision for scoring significantly affects the correlation between rummage brightness and altitude. To do this, I am running phylogenetic generalised least square models (PGLS) to see the relation between both of these score types and altitude for various species. As it happens, using both human scores and scores which model how bright an avian visual system would see plumage both get no significant correlation, but I want to compare if the PGLS which use human scores are significantly distinct from those which use scores which model how bright an avian visual system would see plumage? That is to say, can I compare the outputs of two PGLS? I am using R for this analysis, but answers do not have to provide a solution in R, though would be much appreciated if they do.